# How to create a seamless Wireless Network using Powerline Adapter and 3 Wireless routers

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, powerline-networking

To be clear, I am not looking for product recommendation, but a solution

I have 3 TP-LINK TL-PA7017 gigabit powerline adapters and one of which is connected to LAN port of my Primary Wireless router TP-Link TL-WR1043 (Main)

I have 2 more wireless routers - WAVLINK-WN578HR2 (can have 3 modes - Router/Repeater/AP) and GL Inet AR750S (also 3 modes - Router/Extender/AP)

I tried doing the following:

1. Connected GL-Inet AR7505 (LAN port) to the pairing powerline adapter in a room where signal is unstable.
2. Changed the operation mode to Router
3. Changed the SSID
4. Changed SSID name/password/security type to match main wireless router -
   and kept channels etc. to auto.
5. Repeated 2-4 but for the third router - WAVLINK-WN578HR2

My problems:
i) I can only see one device (GL-Inet) but not the other when checking main routers' DHCP client list.

ii) When I try to go to the assigned address 192.168.0.102 - I don't see the admin menu for secondary router.

iii) I tried swapping the LAN port (of secondary/tertiary routers) with WAN port - but no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

I just want to make sure that I don't have to change my home router SSID every time I change floors. The house has really difficult areas so I am using Powerline Extenders to expand the coverage and then using seamless wifi switching.

I know I can just connect secondary/tertiary routers using different SSIDs and it would just work. But this means I have to constantly keep switching to different networks.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the DHCP service is *disabled* on all routers except for the primary one. Wherever you try to connect, make sure your phone/laptop gets an IP address from the primary router.

Using a LAN port on secondary routers is mostly correct. You actually *don't* want the secondary routers to be "routers" – you want them to act as nothing more but layer-2 bridges.

This means the secondary routers' WAN port can only be used if the router is set to the correct mode, usually "AP" mode (it varies between models, but it's certainly *not* "router" mode) – but on the other hand, the LAN ports will always work, as they're already bridged to Wi-Fi all the time.

Comment: "Make sure that DHCP service is disabled" - that's what I am trying to figure out i.e. where to turn it off - Because I cannot seem to find it for those two models

Comment: Then try switching them to "AP mode", this should disable DHCP as well.

Comment: But using access point on GL-Inet AR750S, you cannot turn it to AP and leave LAN connection open, you need to use Wifi to bridge it with the SSID you're connecting to :(

Comment: Sounds like its firmware simply doesn't support the mode you want, then. (And it misuses the "AP" term for what is really repeater mode...)